# refresh a div data on click

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to refresh the data of my div when I click on link that shows the div. 
I could not find answer, even though there were a lot of similar answers.

So what I have:
I have several divs, that got shown by click on links.

I have the main page, I have:

```
<div id="#id">
<select id="list">
<?php inlucde('getlist.php'); //basically retrieves the options
</select>
</div>
```

in my php file:

```
<?php
//basically getting connected to mysql, 
//and retrieve data from a table;
echo "<option> data </option>";
echo "<option> data </option>";
...
?>
```

The problem here is, the data I want to show is updated in another 
div, I am updating the data in mysql, since the both divs are on the same page, The updated data is not shown in the list, when I refresh the page, it shows.

So what I want, is when I click the link to show the list, I would like to refresh the list before showing it.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: And, how can I do it? a bit more details maybe?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
Ajax is the simplest method for you.
But I really think that you need some more practice before you`ll be able to use it properly :)

Comment: In Ajax function you are defining params, method of request and URL that you would like to get response from and what to do when the response will come back. That's where you need to fill your select with options. Look for examples in WWW :)

Comment: I tried to create select list in php file, and call the php with ajax, whenever I click to the link, but jquery does not see the list anymore. So when the list created, I want do retrieve the some other data according to which item is selected. But jquery does not see it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is refreshing the data upon change which can only be done (without page refresh) with the use of [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Since you have tagged jquery I would suggest reading about [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Long story short:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.php",     // your server script that will reply to your request.
  type: "POST",          // method used for your request.
  data: { id : menuId }, // data to pass to your server script.
  dataType: "html"       // the response type you expect from your server
});

request.done(function( msg ) {  // executed when you get a successful reply
  alert(msg);                   // your reply is inside msg variable
});

request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {  // in case of an error this is being executed
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});

request.always(function() {  // will always be executed after success or failure
  alert( "Request completed." )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mine

```
    formData = {
        id: $("#id");
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "getlist.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            //success handling
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //error handling
        }
    });
```